# NetSuite Advanced HTML template: body text showing over header

Tags: html, netsuite

I'm fairly new to HTML so apologies for my ignorance.
I have set a header using the following format -

```
<macrolist>
<macro id="nlheader">
    Header
        </macro>
    </macrolist>
```

The header is correctly fixed to the top of every page but the body text is going over it. How to I stop this?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You'll have to show more of your code, both the html and the css stylesheet (if you're using one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `header-height` attribute in the `<body>` to tell the template how far down to start the body text:

```
<body header="nlheader" header-height="10%">
```